# Html5 div over canvas crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I try to put a div over a fullpage canvas.Works great in Chrome but in firefox and ie9 it goes 'kaput'.

Here is a link to that code (tried in firefox chrome and ie9) only chrome seems to work;

http://jsbin.com/ubolan/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE9 document doesn't have the properties `document.width/document.height` so you are setting the canvas width/height to 0.

Try using

```
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

or

```
canvas.width = $(document).width();
canvas.height = $(document).height();
```

Comment: Ok .Thanks very much .I fixed it. Good to know about document properties.Again thanks